# Grid showing empty rows extjs

Tags: extjs

Here, store loads data from databse(firebug shows) but all rows are empty...Please help.I cant find the reason behind...

**Store**

```
autoLoad: true,
model: 'CustomerService.model.OrderModel',
idProperty: 'id',
fields: [{
    name: 'id',
    type: 'int'
}, {
    name: 'name',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'quantity',
    type: 'int'
}, {
    name: 'receivedquantity',
    type: 'int'
}],
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    url: 'data/Getall.php',
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        successProperty: 'success'
    }
}
});
```

**Here is Model:**

```
Ext.define('CustomerService.model.OrderModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model'
});
```

**here is view:**

```
Ext.define('CustomerService.view.customer.List', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mylist',
    selModel: Ext.create('Ext.selection.CheckboxModel', {
        checkOnly: false
    }),
    store: 'OrderStore',
    forceFit: true, //Fit to container:: columnLines:true, height:132, width:200, autoResizeColumns:true, initComponent:function(){

    this.columns = [{
        header: 'name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        header: 'Quantity',
        dataIndex: 'quantity',
    }, {
        header: 'Received Quantity',
        dataIndex: 'receivedquantity'
    }];
    this.callParent(arguments);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your using a `model` in your `store` you should define the `fields` in your `model` instead of defining them in your `store`.

```
Ext.define('CustomerService.model.OrderModel', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'quantity',
        type: 'int'
    }, {
        name: 'receivedquantity',
        type: 'int'
    }],
});
```

> [Ext.data.Store fileds](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-fields):
>
> This may be used in place of specifying a model configuration. The
>   fields should be a set of Ext.data.Field configuration objects. The
>   store will automatically create a Ext.data.Model with these fields. In
>   general this configuration option should only be used for simple
>   stores like a two-field store of ComboBox. For anything more
>   complicated, such as specifying a particular id property or
>   associations, a Ext.data.Model should be defined and specified for the
>   model config.

Comment: ohh thanks,i thought. It looks first in the store then in the model.Someone told me to "create everything in the store,do not use model"

Comment: You accepted because it solved your problem? Is the code working for you now? Because it seems to me there are other issues with your code.